# Why don’t current tools support collecting memory bandwidth usage data at process granularity?

Tags: profiling, intel-pmu, memory-bandwidth

Common hardware indicators such as IPC and cache miss rates support data collection at process granularity.

Why does the memory bandwidth usage only support the collection of the whole machine dimension? This is true both in [Intel's PCM tool](https://github.com/intel/pcm) and [AMD's uProf tool](https://www.amd.com/en/developer/uprof.html).

Is this due to limitations of the hardware PMU capabilities?